# How check annual date condition

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

I have trouble in calculating annual year condition.

Here in my project we are allowing user to create one plan at any time but their end date will be fix which is (March-31). 
User can create only one plan per year. In Next year again they can create one new plan and same way goes for all next years.

Now my problem is how to check this condition that user has already created plan for this year?

I am getting plan created date(From MySQL) in array as follow :

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => 2010-04-19 08:20:45
    [1] => 2011-09-19 08:20:45
    [2] => 2012-05-19 08:20:45
    [3] => 2013-08-19 08:20:45
 )
```

I am not getting right way to implement this.

Comment: `$prevYear = substr($array[3], 4); if($prevYear == date('Y')) {`

Comment: Do u want to check the value is already exist in array?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv yeah

Comment: @Daan got this, just check the above comment, that's probably the fastest way ;)

Comment: Can't you just test if the end date is after the current date?

Comment: @Daan,Barmar What if i have created my last plan on 2014-02-04?

Comment: substr($arrayelement,4) will always get the first 4 elements of the string, therefore the year, so just check if substr($arrayelement,4) is equal to the current year (date("Y")) and you're done. Isn't it what you need to do? Or do you need to compare both date and time?

Comment: @briosheje what my point is if i create plan on 2014-02-04 then in april i should be able to create one more new plan as here annual year i am following is April-13 to March-14. but i think based on Dann condition it will not allow

Comment: Answer the question: Do you need to compare only the **year** or the WHOLE datetime element? Dann's answer is comparing the year, because that's what you asked in the question. If you need to compare the whole date, you can use strtotime http://php.net/manual/it/function.strtotime.php on both the array elements and the current date (date("now"))

Comment: @briosheje here in this scenario i have to compare whole date, Year won't be sufficient.

Comment: @Barmar here in this scenario i have to compare whole date, Year won't be sufficient

Comment: `WHERE end_date > NOW()` in MySQL

Comment: then use mysql for such a task or, in php, convert the array elements in time using strtotime and compare them with the current date, like such: `$currdate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));`, `if ($currdate > strtotime($arrayElement)) { // the date is greater than when it was created } else { // the date is smaller than when it was created }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
   $last = strtotime("2014-04-01");

   $years_diff = (int) date("Y") - (int) date("Y", $last);

   if($years_diff == 1){
      if(date('Y-m-d') > date('Y-m-d', strtotime((date('Y',$last)+1)."-03-31")))
      {
        echo 'Let them create new plan'; exit;
      }
   }
   else if($years_diff == 0){
     if(date('m',$last) > 03){
         echo 'Sorry ! you can not create'; exit;
     }
     if(date('Y-m-d') > date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y',$last)."-03-31")))
     {
        echo 'Let them create new plan'; exit;
     }   
   }
   else
      echo 'Let them create new plan'; exit;
```

Hope it may help you :)

Comment: Awesome dude. Worked like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

## Attempt #1

First way is the best: you compare 2 dates' years (in your case - datetimes). Current year must be larger than last date's year: 2010 - 2014. Then you compare days and months in same way but with some more precision:

```
$current = time();
$last = strtotime("2010-04-19 08:20:45");
$years_diff = (int) date("Y", $current) - (int) date("Y", $last);
$months_diff = (int) date("n", $current) - (int) date("n", $last);
$days_diff = (int) date("j", $current) - (int) date("j", $last);

$condition = false;
if ($years_diff == 1) { // ABOUT one year ago when last plan was created
    if ($months_diff == 0) { // Current month is month when plan was created
        if ($days_diff >= 0) { // Larger than or equal to day when last plan was created
            $condition = true;
        }
    }
    else if ($months_diff > 0) { // Next months in new year
        $condition = true;
    }
}
else if ($years_diff > 1) { // ABOUT 2 or more years ago when last plan was created
    $condition = true;
}
```

There's compressed version of condition:

```
$condition = (($years_diff == 1) ? (($months_diff == 0) ? ($days_diff >= 0) : ($months_diff > 0)) : ($years_diff > 1));
```

## Attempt #2

Simple way is calculating a difference between last and current date (in your case - "datetime"). Then you check whether difference is larger than or equal to 365 days.

```
$current = time();
$last = strtotime("2010-04-19 08:20:45");
$days_diff = ($current - $last) / (60 * 60 * 24);
$condition = ($days_diff >= 365);
```